# Lotusscript how to display only tens of numbers

Tags: lotusscript

In my LotusScript code I have a progress indicator:

```
docCount = AllDocs.Count
current = 0
Print Cstr(Round(current / docCount * 100, 0)) + "% copied"
```

I want to reduce the number of Print statements by only display tens of numbers e.g.
10% copied
20% copied

How can I do this? is there a way to check if a number is an integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample below is a bit quick and dirty, but basically you can achieve this using the modulo operation:

```
If (Round(current / docCount*100,0) Mod 10) = 0 then
do your print 
end if
```

In LotusScriopt modulo is implemented using the Mod operator which is documented in the designer help:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/LSAZ_MOD_OPERATOR.html